# Wordpress: Add form that posts to a php script

Tags: wordpress, forms

I just installed wordpress, still getting the hang of it.

Basically, I want to build a form with 5 fields (firstname, lastname, tele,address,zip) that posts to xyz.com/x.php.

I don't see any way to actually do this, but I am quite sure I have seen this on other wordpress sites (I am self hosting).

Ideas or links would be appreciated!

Comment: do u need ajax? or just x.php with Inited WP core?

Comment: No need for ajax, just a simple form that posts to an external URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not something WordPress does. If you have x.php you can simply create a custom template in your theme with the HTML of the form you'd like.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template

Answer (score 0):

your aim is gathering all people's that they fill the form in the x.php page? 
if it is this you can do this:
1- set the form method too post
2- set the action to process.php
3- you can get the values in process.php using> $_POST['input_name'];
4- insert values in MySQL table
5- header to x.php